# How to validate no duplications with Yup

Tags: reactjs, forms, yup

I have a validation that only validates its fields by checking if they are break its only rules, but it allows duplications inside the Array.

I want some sort of condition that won't allow duplicated values inside of it.

My object:

```
respostas: Yup.array()
    .of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        nome: Yup.string()
          .trim()
          .max(1000, Messages.RESPOSTA_ENQUETE_TAMANHO_MAXIMO)
          .required(Messages.CAMPO_OBRIGATORIO)
      })
    )
    .required(Messages.RESPOSTA_QUANTIDADE_MINIMA)
```

For example, I would have an array like this: [aaa,bbb,aaa] allowed, but I don't want this duplication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To validate this you can write your own `.test()`. You can add the following test to the Yup object.

```
.test("Unique", "Values need te be unique", values => {
    return (new Set(values)).size === values.length;
})
```

The error will be added to the object in general, not at the specific field.

Comment: This works, but unable to add error to the duplicate input. Any way to add error to duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

```
const { addOrEdit, recordForEdit, fabricTypeList } = props;
const duplicateNameCheck = (list, value) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (value === list[i].name) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
};

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup
    .string()
    .required("Name is required")
    .test("Unique", "Name needs te be unique", (values) => {
      return duplicateNameCheck(fabricTypeList, values);
    }),
});

const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: initialValues,
  validationSchema: validationSchema,
  onSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
    setSubmitting(true);
    addOrEdit(values, resetForm, setSubmitting);
  },
});
```

Comment: @padaleiana 
1. From yup test() function we can get that field value.Like .test((values) => {
      return fiberId = values
    }),
here test function setting it's value to a global variable. 
2. we can also call a custom validation function through test() function. This time test() function except true/false value. false return means the field value is duplicate.